# LIBSVM assigning parameter c

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I'm trying to assign different values to c in LIBSVM in matlab. the code line is

`svmtrain(Ytrain, Xtrain, '-c C_vector(iter)')`

for different iterations and

`C_vector=1:10:100`

But this does not seem to work and prints 
`Error: C <= 0`

ps: I have tested the `svmtrain(Ytrain, Xtrain, '-c 1')` and `svmtrain(Ytrain, Xtrain, '-c 11')`, which are the first two values of C_vector, and they perfectly work.
Any ideas what's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Note that `svmtrain` has been deprecated in favour of `templateSVM`, `fitcecoc` and `predict` from the Machine Learning Toolbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svmtrain` cannot `eval` your subscript. Use instead:

```
 svmtrain(Ytrain, Xtrain, sprintf('-c %d', C_vector(iter)));
```

that will write in the option string the value of the subscript expression.

Comment: @SarahESL If so, please select the answer as correct.

Comment: just another question, I had other strings in that quotation as well : `svmtrain(Ytrain, Xtrain, '-t 2 -g lambda_hat(j)/gamma -c C_vector(i)')`, but just had problem with `-c` (e.g `svmtrain(Ytrain, Xtrain, '-t 2 -g lambda_hat(j)/gamma -c 1')` had no error)...could you tell me why? Thanks

Comment: @SarahESL Actually you just believe it worked, but it did not. `svmtrain()` is a MEX function that uses the `atof()` function to convert the arguments from ASCII to floating point. This function is from the standard C library, so it is oblivious of MATLAB syntax, so there's no way  `-g lambda_hat(j)/gamma` would be automagically interpreted as a valid float. The behaviour for `atof` is to return 0.0 when it doesn't understand the input. That may be valid value for `-g` option, but not valid value for `-c`. That's why it didn't raise any error.